# Bootstrap 3: Phone and desktop layout only, no tablet layout needed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I like Bootstrap 3 very much, but most of the time I don't want to create an extra design for tablet devices. So I only need the screen-xs and screen-lg option. I don't need screen-sm and screen-md.
When a user visits my site with a tablet, I want to display the screen-lg site. It should just resize to his device (like any other traditional non-responsive site).
**Example is: http://www.egg.de**

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If you use only `col-sm-*` columns instead of `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*`, your design will only adjust on at 768px and above (or below, if you prefer to think of it as desktop-first).

Comment: Yes, that's correct but  that's  not what I want. Because the font and buttons for example will keep the same size on sm, md and lg! That's not like a static page. They archieved what I want, but I don't know how they did it: http://www.egg.de

Comment: they're not using bootstrap, but I don't see how it's a different result than this would achieve. can you show us what you've tried?